# buttons not firing their jQuery functions on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a set of buttons

**Code**

```js
$(".form-type-selector").on('click touchstart', function() {
  $(".form-type-selector").removeClass("primary-btn");
  $(".form-type-selector").addClass("secondary-btn");
  $(this).removeClass("secondary-btn");
  $(this).addClass("primary-btn");
});

$("#one-time-btn").on('click touchstart', function() {
  $(".generic-div").hide();
  $("#one-time-form").show();
});
$("#monthly-btn").on('click touchstart', function() {
  $(".generic-div").hide();
  $("#monthly-form").show();
});
```

```css
.secondary-btn {background-color: silver}
.primary-btn {background-color: crimson}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-type-wrapper">
  <p class="section-header-container">Pick a button</p>
  <button id="one-time-btn" class="btn primary-btn form-type-selector">One</button>
  <button id="monthly-btn" class="btn secondary-btn form-type-selector">Two</button>
  <button id="annual-btn" class="btn secondary-btn form-type-selector">Three</button>
  <button id="forever-btn" class="btn secondary-btn form-type-selector">Four</button>
</div>
```

In all cases when you click one of these buttons the following functions are fired

**Function #1** - sets the active class for the button

```
$(".form-type-selector").on('click touchstart', function () {
   $(".form-type-selector").removeClass("primary-btn");
   $(".form-type-selector").addClass("secondary-btn");
   $(this).removeClass("secondary-btn");
   $(this).addClass("primary-btn");
});
```

**Function #2** - does a hide/show to display the correct element associated with the button

```
$("#one-time-btn").on('click touchstart', function () {
    $(".generic-div").hide();
    $("#one-time-form").show();       
});
$("#monthly-btn").on('click touchstart', function () {
    $(".generic-div").hide();
    $("#monthly-form").show();
});
```

Typically I'd use a regular `$(element).click(function ()` for this but I'd seen other people with this issue and most of the accepted answers said to use `touchstart` in addition to the click.

In my case parts of the functions are firing but not all. The lines of code defined by `$(this)` are seemingly being ignored. Any ideas why this is happening? Is `$(this)` not supported on mobile?

**UPDATE:**

In the event someone else encounters a similar problem and stumbles across this issue. An `:active` pseudo call on the CSS classes got this to work on mobile.

So it wasn't enough to just define the class and set it's background color it wanted it like this:

```
.primary-btn,
.primary-btn:active {
   background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: It's working fine for me on Android/Chrome

Comment: @EduardoMolteni I just made a fiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/yxmpnfkd/ and on mobile it works for me to... must be something else up/down stream in my application messing with it. Thanks for having a look and editing the original question

Comment: ok, no problem. A common issue is that `$(this)` sometimes it's not what you think it is.